# Why does multiplying REGEXEXTRACT value return incorrect results?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to pull a the first line of date from a particular cell - in this case BO17 - and then multiply it by 25. You see I have the REGEXEXTRACT formula, which I have attempted to place into a larger multiplication formula. However, every time I run this, the result is 25, as opposed to 84(25).This is my current function.

```
=PRODUCT((REGEXEXTRACT(BO17, "[0-9]+")),25)
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=PRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(BO17, "[0-9]+")*1, 25)
```

or just:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(BO17, "[0-9]+")*25
```

Comment: I like this kind of refactoring `=REGEXEXTRACT(BO17, "[0-9]+")*25`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `REGEXEXTRACT` returns `TEXT` type. You need to convert it to number.

```
=PRODUCT(--REGEXEXTRACT(BO17, "[0-9]+"),25)
```

- `--` The double unary operator can be used to convert `TEXT` to `NUMBER` type
- Alternatively, you can use `VALUE()` function

Comment: `--` first time encountering this.

Comment: @Osm There's even a user active here by that name: ``@doubleunary``

Comment: Im just about to read [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73877469/19529694) here.