# Is there any formula that i can use to how to show up value (month) in between from start to end date in spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Is there any formula that I can use to show up each month according to start & end date in spreadsheet.

Example:

```
Start Date:2022-07-22
End Date:2022-10-22
```

I expected formula to extract value something like this

```
Jul - Aug - Sep - Oct
```

I've tried formula

`=IF(A2="","",IF(TEXT(B2,"MM")-TEXT(A2,"MM")>1,CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"MMM")&" - "&text(EDATE(A2,1),"MMM")&" - "&TEXT(B2,"MMM")),IF(TEXT(A2,"MMM")=TEXT(B2,"MMM"),TEXT(A2,"MMM"),CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"MMM")&" - "&TEXT(B2,"MMM")))))` but it only give me correct value if there is up to 3 month period between start & end date.

[Here's a link to the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jVI64ORl5C8E5SM6styqEEtTS9esfSN0zm2ZtdO7VaM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Your sheet is private. Make it public.

Comment: Done, kindly check.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Im sorry, im a newbie here, thank you for the input sir.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, its done, thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the difference in dates in months using `DATEDIF` and get dates in each  intervening month using `EOMONTH`+`SEQUENCE` and convert the end of month dates to `TEXT`:

| Start Date | End Date | Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022-10-30 | Jul - Aug - Sep - Oct |
| 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-31 | Aug |
| 2022-07-03 | 2022-11-01 | Jul - Aug - Sep - Oct - Nov |

Drag fill formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" - ",TEXT(EOMONTH(A2,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,EOMONTH(B2,),"M")+1)-1),"mmm")))
```

Or as a self adjusting array formula:

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(a, ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" - ",TEXT(EOMONTH(a,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(a,EOMONTH(OFFSET(a,0,1),),"M")+1)-1),"mmm")))))
```

This should be faster and efficient than getting all the dates and filtering them out one by one, thereby [reducing space  and time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815258/what-factors-determine-the-memory-used-in-lambda-functions).

Comment: well thank you for your help, really appreciate it, so far this formula is the simplest as well as easy to understand for a newbie like me who trying to understand formula like this

Comment: @byrmn__ Great. Consider accepting it, if you find it better than others.

Answer (score 2):

For single cell can try-

```
=JOIN("-",UNIQUE(INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B2-A2+1,1,A2),"mmm"))))
```

For spill array-

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(9^9,B2:B)),LAMBDA(x,JOIN("-",UNIQUE(INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(INDEX(x,2)-INDEX(x,1)+1,1,INDEX(x,1)),"mmm"))))))
```

See your sheet.

[image]

Comment: Sweet use of `INDEX`

Comment: @Osm Yes, this approach seems faster.

Comment: May know what is 9^9 use for?

Comment: im just trying to understand and learn from all the solutions I get from here

Comment: `9^9` used to detect last date entry row in a column. if column is text type data then use `zzz`.

Comment: well, noted, thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Use `sequence()`, `edate()` and `join()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( map( 
  A2:A, B2:B, 
  lambda( 
    start, end, 
    if( 
      isdate(start) * isdate(end), 
      join( 
        " - ", 
        text( 
          edate( 
            start, 
            sequence( 
              12 * (year(end) - year(start)) + month(end) - month(start) + 1, 
              1, 0 
            ) 
          ), 
          "MMM" 
        ) 
      ), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  ) 
) )
```

Comment: can you provide me a solution if I want to make it to be "MMM" format for the result?